# Android Firebase Merging multiple queries

Tags: android, firebase

I have this table on firebase;

```
{
"car1" : {
"carId" : "123asd45",
"carImageUrl" : "url",
"carName" : "Champion"
},
"car2" : {
"carId" : "123aa456",
"carImageUrl" : "url",
"carName" : "Super"
},
"car3" : {
"carId" : "1234ew5",
"carImageUrl" : "url",
"carName" : "A"
}
}
```

And I am using firebase ui adapter like;

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                   .getReference()
                   .child("carmodels")
                   .orderByChild("carName")
                   .equalTo(MYFILTER1)
                   .limitToLast(30);
  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Car> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Car>()
                    .setQuery(query, Car.class)
                    .build();
```

The above code working fine, but what I would like to do is; to filter by multiple strings like;

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                   .getReference()
                   .child("carmodels")
                   .orderByChild("carName")
                   .equalTo(MYFILTER1)
                   .limitToLast(30);
 Query query2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                   .getReference()
                   .child("carmodels")
                   .orderByChild("carName")
                   .equalTo(MYFILTER2)
                   .limitToLast(30);
```

Then merge them query results and give it to options;

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Car> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Car>()
                .setQuery(MERGEDQuery, Car.class)
                .build();
```

So is it possible something like that ? Or do you suggest another solution for this ? Thank you

EDIT:

I have lots of Filters so using another child on firebase like "filters":"filter1_filter2_filter3.." can be problematic.

Comment: What would you like to return that combined query as a result? All the cars that corespond to MYFILTER1, MYFILTER2 and so on?

Comment: @AlexMamo there are lots of filters. I answered my question, you can check how I solved it. I dont know maybe this is bad way to solve but it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can make some ninja moves here by combining filter keys on a single attribute on your data structure.

`{
"car1" : {
"carId" : "123asd45",
"carImageUrl" : "url",
"carName" : "Champion",
"filters" : "MYFILTER1_MYFILTER2"
},
"car2" : {
"carId" : "123aa456",
"carImageUrl" : "url",
"carName" : "Super",
"filters" : "MYFILTER1_MYFILTER2"
},
"car3" : {
"carId" : "1234ew5",
"carImageUrl" : "url",
"carName" : "A",
"filters" : "MYFILTER1_MYFILTER2"
}
}`

then on your query:

```
 Query query2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
               .getReference()
               .child("carmodels")
               .orderByChild("carName")
               .equalTo(MYFILTER1_MYFILTER2)
               .limitToLast(30);
```

Comment: thank you but I have lots of filters, in that case that can be problem

Answer (score 0):

For who needs a solution to that problem, I solved this problem to filter items in my recycleview adapter. Filtered items visible on recycleview, others invisible now.